# How to detect touch between several UIViews?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, touch

The case is that I have several UIViews on the main screen and I arranged them just like tablecells one by one.
I want to implement a function that I randomly tapped a UIView and moving my finger between each of them(like hover). When I touched a UIView which is different form the last time I touched, the device will vibrate.

Until now I was trying to use "

- (void)touchesMoved" method to implement it, but it didn't work. I gave each of the uiview a specific tag. When I call "- (void)touchesBegan" method, I will update the current tag number. I expected the "- (void)touchesMoved" method would help me to refresh the current tag of the view, but it didn't. It remained the same tag number I have update in "- (void)touchesBegan" method.

Here is the code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    currentTag = touch.view.tag;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)touch.view.tag);
    if (touch.view.tag != currentTag) {
        NSLog(@"Vibrate");
        currentTag = touch.view.tag;
    }
}
```

Wish to get some help~

Thank u.

Comment: After a touch event are you reloading the view? The subviews are outlets or actions?

Comment: Nope, I didn't reload the view and the subviews are just outlets.

Answer (score 2):

Add your views to a container view and overwrite it's `touchesMoved` etc and do the bounds check yourself:

```
-(void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, location)){
            if (view.tag != currentTag) {
                NSLog(@"Vibrate");
                currentTag = touch.view.tag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using scrollview.
You can create tiles in scrollview.Please find below code.

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

```
int column = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < data.count; ++i) {


    UIView *tile = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(column*230+24, 20, 200, 160)]];

    tile.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tile.tag = i+1 ;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [tile addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


    [scrollView addSubview:tile];


    column++;



}


[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(column*225+24,view.frame.size.height)];
```

}

Let me know if any clarification required..Happy coding